# Ruby hash length or size returns nothing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a rake task in ruby :

```
namespace :generate do
  desc "Export to txt"
  task :txt, [:filename, :item_id] => :environment do |t, args|
    puts "aaaaaaaaaaaaa #{args.length}"
    puts "ssssssss #{args.size}"
    puts "bbbbbbbbbb #{args}"

    args.each do | arg |
        puts "#{arg}"
    end
  end
end
```

First two puts don't return anything just `aaaaaaaaaaa` and `ssssssss` is printed, however bbbbbb print does return my args and even when I go trough each argument they are printed. What am I doing wrong?

**update**

I started rake task like this :

`rake generate:txt[Temp.txt,22]`

bbbbbbbbb prints :

```
bbbbbbbbbb {:filename=>"Temp.txt", :item_id=>"22"}
```

Each loop prints :

```
[:filename, "Temp.txt"]
[:item_id, "22"]
```

Comment: try with a splat: `do |t, *args|`

Comment: what did you pass as the parameter?

Comment: @Evgeniy Ryzhkov please see my update

Comment: Your each block needs to take two parameters, a key and a value. This is how hashes implement Enumerable#each.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`args` is not an `Hash`, is a `Rake::TaskArguments`:

`puts args.class #=> Rake::TaskArguments`

probably this class doesn't implement `size` and `length`; converting to hash works for me:

```
namespace :generate do
  desc "Export to txt"
  task :txt, [:filename, :item_id] => :environment do |t, args|
    puts "args class: #{args.class}"
    args = args.to_hash
    puts "args to hash: #{args.inspect}"
    puts "aaaaaaaaaaaaa #{args.length}"
    puts "ssssssss #{args.size}"
    puts "bbbbbbbbbb #{args}"

    args.each do | arg |
        puts "#{arg}"
    end
  end
end
```

prints:

```
$ rake generate:txt[Temp.txt,22]
Rake::TaskArguments
{:filename=>"Temp.txt", :item_id=>"22"}
aaaaaaaaaaaaa 2
ssssssss 2
bbbbbbbbbb {:filename=>"Temp.txt", :item_id=>"22"}
[:filename, "Temp.txt"]
[:item_id, "22"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are dealing with an instance of Rake:TaskArguments 
please see http://rake.rubyforge.org/classes/Rake/TaskArguments.html

If you want to treat it like an enumerable, then call to_hash on it.

```
namespace :generate do
  desc "Export to txt"
  task :txt, [:filename, :item_id] => :environment do |t, args|
     puts args.class
     puts "aaaaaaaaaaaaa #{args.to_hash.length}"
     puts "size #{args.to_hash.size}"
     puts "bbbbbbbbbb #{args}"
     args.each do | arg |
    puts "#{arg}"
     end
  end
end
```